# Clicking on any spoiler always opens first

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a news blog on asp-net.
There is a spoiler to the news. There are some news with spoilers on the page. However, if I click on any spoiler (first, second, third), then only the first opens in any case. I understand that it because of all buttons and fields have the same id. How can I implement the connection between the button and the spoiler? A specific spoiler must be opened after clicking on it, but not the first.

```
<div>
   <label>Body</label>
       <button type="button" id="button">Add spoiler</button>
   <textarea id="spoilerField" asp-for="Body"></textarea>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var textarea = document.getElementById("spoilerField");
        var button = document.getElementById("button");
        button.onclick = function () {
            var len = textarea.value.length,
                start = textarea.selectionStart,
                end = textarea.selectionEnd,
                sel = textarea.value.substring(start, end),
                replace = '<input type="checkbox" id="spoiler2"/><label for="spoiler2">SEE SPOILER</label><div class="spoiler">' + sel + '</div>';
            textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, start) + replace + textarea.value.substring(end, len);
        }
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should still make those ids unique regardless, you could, for example, add elements to the page using a for loop with Razor and an index and joining the 2.

The id would then look something like:

```
id="spoiler_@i"
```

That aside, you should be looking at [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) or [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to select those elements and do what you need to do.

Comment: I suspect giving them a class rather than different ids may be worth considering.

Comment: Yeah I agree, it was more to illustrate that ids should be unique regardless.